# Highcharts is not defined >> angular 2 >> typescript

Tags: angular

I am new to angular 2 and trying to make activity-gauge highchart in angular 2.
using example of "https://www.highcharts.com/demo/gauge-activity". But facing an error continuous :- "Uncaught ReferenceError: Highcharts is not defined at solid-gauge.src.js:18"

My code:-

**App.module.ts**

```
import * as Highcharts from 'highcharts'; 
import * as more from 'highcharts/highcharts-more.src';  
import * as solidGauge from 'highcharts/modules/solid-gauge'; 
import { GauveComponent } from './gauve/gauve.component';
more(Highcharts), 
solidGauge(Highcharts),
```

component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import * as Highcharts from 'highcharts'; 
import * as more from 'highcharts/highcharts-more.src';  
import * as solidGauge from 'highcharts/modules/solid-gauge'; 
more(Highcharts);
solidGauge(Highcharts);
import '../../assets/js/gauge.js';
declare var gauvedata: any;

@Component({
  selector: 'app-gauve',
  templateUrl: './gauve.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./gauve.component.css']
})
export class GauveComponent implements OnInit {

constructor() {}
ngOnInit() {
   gauvedata.init();
}
```

// Js for highchart

```
 var gauvedata = (function() { 
    return { 
      init: function() {
          alert("inside gauvescript");
Highcharts.chart('container', {

    chart: {
        type: 'solidgauge',
        height: '110%',
        events: {
            render: renderIcons
        }
    },

    title: {
        text: 'Activity',
        style: {
            fontSize: '24px'
        }
    },

    tooltip: {
        borderWidth: 0,
        backgroundColor: 'none',
        shadow: false,
        style: {
            fontSize: '16px'
        },
        pointFormat: '{series.name}<br><span style="font-size:2em; color: {point.color}; font-weight: bold">{point.y}%</span>',
        positioner: function (labelWidth) {
            return {
                x: (this.chart.chartWidth - labelWidth) / 2,
                y: (this.chart.plotHeight / 2) + 15
            };
        }
    },

    pane: {
        startAngle: 0,
        endAngle: 360,
        background: [{ // Track for Move
            outerRadius: '112%',
            innerRadius: '88%',
            backgroundColor: Highcharts.Color(Highcharts.getOptions().colors[0])
                .setOpacity(0.3)
                .get(),
            borderWidth: 0
        }, { // Track for Exercise
            outerRadius: '87%',
            innerRadius: '63%',
            backgroundColor: Highcharts.Color(Highcharts.getOptions().colors[1])
                .setOpacity(0.3)
                .get(),
            borderWidth: 0
        }, { // Track for Stand
            outerRadius: '62%',
            innerRadius: '38%',
            backgroundColor: Highcharts.Color(Highcharts.getOptions().colors[2])
                .setOpacity(0.3)
                .get(),
            borderWidth: 0
        }]
    },

    yAxis: {
        min: 0,
        max: 100,
        lineWidth: 0,
        tickPositions: []
    },

    plotOptions: {
        solidgauge: {
            dataLabels: {
                enabled: false
            },
            linecap: 'round',
            stickyTracking: false,
            rounded: true
        }
    },

    series: [{
        name: 'Move',
        data: [{
            color: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[0],
            radius: '112%',
            innerRadius: '88%',
            y: 80
        }]
    }, {
        name: 'Exercise',
        data: [{
            color: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[1],
            radius: '87%',
            innerRadius: '63%',
            y: 65
        }]
    }, {
        name: 'Stand',
        data: [{
            color: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[2],
            radius: '62%',
            innerRadius: '38%',
            y: 50
        }]
    }]
});

          } 
    } 
  })(gauvedata||{})



  function renderIcons() {

    // Move icon
    if (!this.series[0].icon) {
        this.series[0].icon = this.renderer.path(['M', -8, 0, 'L', 8, 0, 'M', 0, -8, 'L', 8, 0, 0, 8])
            .attr({
                'stroke': '#303030',
                'stroke-linecap': 'round',
                'stroke-linejoin': 'round',
                'stroke-width': 2,
                'zIndex': 10
            })
            .add(this.series[2].group);
    }
    this.series[0].icon.translate(
        this.chartWidth / 2 - 10,
        this.plotHeight / 2 - this.series[0].points[0].shapeArgs.innerR -
            (this.series[0].points[0].shapeArgs.r - this.series[0].points[0].shapeArgs.innerR) / 2
    );

    // Exercise icon
    if (!this.series[1].icon) {
        this.series[1].icon = this.renderer.path(
            ['M', -8, 0, 'L', 8, 0, 'M', 0, -8, 'L', 8, 0, 0, 8,
                'M', 8, -8, 'L', 16, 0, 8, 8]
            )
            .attr({
                'stroke': '#ffffff',
                'stroke-linecap': 'round',
                'stroke-linejoin': 'round',
                'stroke-width': 2,
                'zIndex': 10
            })
            .add(this.series[2].group);
    }
    this.series[1].icon.translate(
        this.chartWidth / 2 - 10,
        this.plotHeight / 2 - this.series[1].points[0].shapeArgs.innerR -
            (this.series[1].points[0].shapeArgs.r - this.series[1].points[0].shapeArgs.innerR) / 2
    );

    // Stand icon
    if (!this.series[2].icon) {
        this.series[2].icon = this.renderer.path(['M', 0, 8, 'L', 0, -8, 'M', -8, 0, 'L', 0, -8, 8, 0])
            .attr({
                'stroke': '#303030',
                'stroke-linecap': 'round',
                'stroke-linejoin': 'round',
                'stroke-width': 2,
                'zIndex': 10
            })
            .add(this.series[2].group);
    }

    this.series[2].icon.translate(
        this.chartWidth / 2 - 10,
        this.plotHeight / 2 - this.series[2].points[0].shapeArgs.innerR -
            (this.series[2].points[0].shapeArgs.r - this.series[2].points[0].shapeArgs.innerR) / 2
    );
 }
```

Comment: Try change to `import * as Highcharts from 'highcharts/highcharts.src'`

Answer (score 0):

This happens because `highcharts/modules/solid-gauge` requires `highcharts` to be already imported. You imported it, but not in the global scope, so the other module can't reference the variable.

I think this could solve your problem:

```
import 'highcharts'; 
declare const Highcharts;
```

Comment: No its not working for my code and I have import highcharts in app.module.ts also.

Answer (score 0):

try it like this :

```
import { Chart } from 'angular-highcharts';


chart = new Chart({
 // properties
     ...
}
```